# I am trying to receive a boolean value from a service in Angular but it only return the whole object

Tags: angular, guard

I'm building a simple service that returns if I'm part of a team or not (a simple true or false). I already validated the backend and it works. The missing part is in my angular app.

The `authentication.service.ts` looks like

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Http, Headers, Response, Request, RequestMethod, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

let roleUrl = environment.apiBaseUrl + 'CoreRole';
let options = new RequestOptions({ withCredentials: true });

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getRoleByName(name): Observable<boolean> {
    console.log('getRoleByName FN: ' + roleUrl + '?name=' + name);
      return this.http.get(roleUrl + '?name=' + name, options)
      .take(1)
      .map(res => <boolean>res.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(error: Response) {
    console.log(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
  }  

}
```

And the `or.guard.ts` looks like

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../services/authentication.service';

@Injectable()
export class OrGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService, private router: Router) { }

  isProjectTeam : boolean;

  canActivate() {

    this.isProjectTeam = <boolean><any> this.authenticationService.getRoleByName("ProjectTeam");

    if(this.isProjectTeam === true)
    {
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/not-authorized');
    }

    return false;
  }

}
```

As result, I'm always taken to `/not-authorized` page because the `isProjectTeam` variable never gets formatted to boolean.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: What is `this.authenticationService.getRoleByName("ProjectTeam")` returning you in `or.guard.ts`?

Comment: Its returning the observable object

`Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: CatchOperator}
operator
:
CatchOperator {caught: Observable, selector: ƒ}
source
:
Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}
_isScalar
:
false
__proto__
:
Object`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to cast an `Observable` to a `boolean`, when you want is to grab the result of the `Observable`.

If you try `let x = this.authenticationService.getRoleByName("ProjectTeam");`, you'll see x is of type `Observable<boolean>`.

You can have `canActivate()` return an `Observable<boolean>` instead of a `boolean`, so change your code like this:

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.authenticationService.getRoleByName("ProjectTeam").map(
        response => {
            if (response) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                this.router.navigateByUrl('/not-authorized');
                return false;
            }
        });
}
```

If you're using TypeScript, one thing you can do when messing with complex objects like this is to break it into pieces with code like `let x = ...`. Intellisense should tell you what types you are dealing with, and give you clues why your code isn't compiling like you think it should.

[More info on the CanActivate guard](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate)

Comment: Thanks! This was the solution!

Comment: Could you explain why `canActivate()` should return an `Observable<boolean>`? Guard canActivate accepts `Observable<boolean>|Promise<boolean>|boolean` so type casting your `boolean` into a `Observable<boolean>` is one step extra that isn't needed. `.catch()` would also be useful after the `.map()` to handle any problem that might arise in the `authenticationService`.

Comment: The OP wanted to use a REST call `getRoleByName` to look up if the route should be allowed. The REST call returns the `Observable<boolean>` by default, so there is no extra casting. In fact, I tried at first to get a `boolean` result for a while before realizing that `canActivate` would accept the `Observable` as well.